# Implementing progress .gif beside upload button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an upload button on my MVC web application which allows a user to upload a file. This file is uploaded onto the system and some async actions are made on this file which may take up to 1/2 minutes. I would like show processing.gif when the users presses the upload button and then hide the .gif when the async actions have finished i.e. when "return View();" has occurred from the HttpPost Upload controller. Can anyone tell me the easiest way to implement this please? I have been messing around with it and can not get it to work correctly. The processing.gif image is currently hidden as you can see from the below code:

The Upload View:

```
<h4><strong>Upload Survey</strong></h4>


<div>
    <p><strong>Upload Surveys in .PDF format</strong></p>
    <br />

    <form class="btn btn-default" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@Url.Action("Upload", "CompletedCamps")">
        <div>
            <input name="file" type="file" class="btn btn-link" required />
            <br />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Import</button>

        </div>

    </form><img id="loading" src="../../Content/processing.gif" alt="Updating ..." style="display:none" />
</div>
<br />
```

The Upload Controllers:

```
    [HttpGet] 
    public ActionResult Upload(int? id)
    {
        CompletedCamp completedCamp = db.CompletedCamps.Find(id);
        return View(completedCamp);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, int? id)
    {
        CompletedCamp completedCamp = db.CompletedCamps.Find(id);

        string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        string filepath = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Surveys/", filename));
        file.SaveAs(filepath);
        await AzureVisionAPI.ExtractToTextFile(filepath);
        ParseSurveyText parse1 = new ParseSurveyText();
        await Task.Run(() => parse1.ParseTextFile(completedCamp.RollNumber, completedCamp.OfficialSchoolName, completedCamp.Date));



        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use client side code like jquery to register the form submit button so that as soon as form is submitted the loader appears. code would be something like:

```
$("form#formId").submit(function(){
   $("img#loading").show();
});
```

Make sure to add id attribute with the id which would be used in the jquery code.

Related html should look like:

```
<form id="formId" class="btn btn-default" method="post" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@Url.Action("Upload", "CompletedCamps")">
......
......
</form><img id="loading" src="../../Content/processing.gif" 
            alt="Updating ..." style="display:none" />
```

Hope it makes sense and give you idea.